# No matching function to call C++

Tags: c++, fstream, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
string path = "MyFile.txt";
ifstream fin;
fin.open(path);

if (!fin.is_open())
{
    cout<< "Fail" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Is OK!" << endl;
}
fin.close();

return 0;
 }
```

Выдает ошибку **no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits >::open(std::string&)** в строке **fin.open(path);**

Comment: C++ 11 включён?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open Перегрузка, принимающая std::string, введена с c++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если с++11 недоступен, попробуйте `path.c_str()`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Лучше сразу конструировать со строкой.